# What tendencies should I be looking out for and how can I use that information to my benefit?

Tags: strategy

I see a lot of poker strategy sites, forums, etc. saying that you should be observing your opponents at the poker table - and understandably so. But what sort of tendencies should I be specifically looking out for? Players who limp monsters, overbetting the pot when a flush rivers, 3-betting the button with mediocre hands like suited connectors, etc.?

And, with that said, how can I use that information to best benefit myself at the table and give myself a bigger edge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always be looking for the weak players first. So this would be things like limping, severely under-betting the pot, playing bad hands etc. With regulars you want to try and figure out which ones are weak and which ones are aggressive. Weak players will fold to 3Bets too much and give up easily postflop. Aggressive players will play back at you too much both preflop and postflop and like to bluff a lot. You can bluff the weak players and trap the aggressive players. Hope this helps!